# how to make any digital pen work in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, digitalpen

i have just bought a digital pen called portronics electropen 2 which connects to computer so that one can make digital notes using real ink and paper it is somewhat like livescribe but uses no special paper. here is the website of the device http://www.portronics.com/electropen-2.html , i was hoping is there's any way i can make it work in ubuntu as i do not want to leave ubuntu and start using windows just for the pen. the mfg provides for the software for windows but no support for linux. is there's any generic driver or app for this kind of pen.

Answer (score 1):

I did some snooping around and was also unable to find anything Linux related with this device.  There is no such thing as an OS-generic driver, since drivers are OS-dependent.

If you really want to use this pen with ubuntu, you might try WINE (https://www.winehq.org)

With WINE, you can run Windows programs just like Ubuntu programs.  That ought to do it nicely.  If not, try to get a refund.

Comment: WINE wouldn't help with drivers just running programs for windows

Comment: 'generic driver or *app*' says the OP.  It is likely with this kind of device you would use a dedicated program.

Comment: Oh sorry the way the answer was worded it sounded like you were saying that WINE helped with drivers. Although I'm not sure if WINE works with USB or Bluetooth (This may have changed I don't know I just recall that it didn't used to work)